Value is undefined with output event emitter in Angular
I have this angular code, which is a function called in emit of output.
addToCart(product: Product) {
  alert(product.name);
}

And on my child component:
  export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() products: Product;
    @Output() onAddToCart: EventEmitter<Product> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() onQuantityUpdate: EventEmitter<Product> = new EventEmitter();
    prod: Product[] = PRODUCTS;
    cart?: Cart;
    id?:number = 1;

    ngOnInit() {}

    isAddVisible = this.prod.map(() => false);
    isAddCartVisible = this.prod.map(() => true);
    cartQuantity = this.prod.map(() => 1);

    togglePropVisible(i: number): void {
      this.isAddVisible[i] = !this.isAddVisible[i];
      this.isAddCartVisible[i] = !this.isAddCartVisible[i];
      this.products[i].cartQuantity = 1;
      this.onAddToCart.emit(this.products);
    }

My question now is why product.name in addToCart is showing an "undefined" value. Can anyone help me with this?

Is this.products an array or an object? Your code is quite confusing. It could be that you actually have an array where you are expecting an object.

You seem to be passing the whole products array to your parent component hence why the name property is resulting in undefined. Can you try passing the selected product by doing something like this this.onAddToCart.emit(this.products[i])

@HarisAli, thank you for that. I finally solved it.

You have typed the products input incorrectly, and are using it sometimes like an array and sometimes like an object. I wonder how TypeScript allowed this. In your onAddToCart event emitter you are expecting a Product object instead of an array. Updated code:
export class ProductListComponent {
  @Input() products: Product[];
  @Output() onAddToCart: EventEmitter<Product> = new EventEmitter();

  togglePropVisible(i: number): void {
    this.products[i].cartQuantity = 1;
    this.onAddToCart.emit(this.products[i]);
  }
}


Haris already given me solution. no need to put "[]" in the product as it will cause error.

@user3312649 then go ahead and fix the errors, this is the correct type. You could have more bugs like this in your application.

I've tried the one you mentioned above but it gave me an error at first, so I dare not change the Product to Product[].
